# I need to send this value to a php variable "c:\" but php guees I close a \"

Tags: php

I need to send this value to a php variable "c:\" but php guees I closed a \" and return an error. If I change to 'c:\' is the same.

Comment: Can you please post your code ? plus what is the returned error ?

Comment: Escape the escape character:  "c:\\"

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am shame now kkkk

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the \, i.e. "c:\"
\ is an escape character, hence \" means use the next " as is and not as a closing "